# Python TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I keep getting this error while trying to run a code for scraping prodcuts in Amazon from an existing .CSV file. Following, the code:

Here i import the required modules

```
import re
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import warnings
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import io
from io import StringIO
from PIL import Image
from html.parser import HTMLParser
```

Here I declare a session object

```
session = HTMLSession()

#ignore warnings
if not sys.warnoptions:
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")

url_array=[] #array for urls
asin_array=[] #array for asin numbers
with open('asin_list.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    asin_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in asin_reader:
        url_array.append(row[0]) #This url list is an array containing all the urls from the excel sheet

#The ASIN Number will be between the dp/ and another /
start = 'dp/'
end = '/'
for url in url_array:
    asin_array.append(url[url.find(start)+len(start):url.rfind(end)]) #this array has all the asin numbers

#declare the header.
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36'}

all_items=[] #The final 2D list containing prices and details of products, that will be converted to a consumable csv

for asin in asin_array:
    item_array=[] #An array to store details of a single product.
    amazon_url="https://www.amazon.com/dp/"+asin #The general structure of a url
    response = session.get(amazon_url, headers=headers, verify=False) #get the response

    item_array.append(response.html.search('a-color-price">${}<')[0]) #Extracting the price


    #Extracting the text containing the product details
    details = response.html


    details=(response.html.search('P.when("ReplacementPartsBulletLoader").execute(function(module){ module.initializeDPX(); }){}</ul>;<'[0]))
    details_arr=[] #Declaring an array to store individual details
    details=re.sub("\n|\r", "", details) #Separate the details from text
    #details_arr=re.findall(r'\>(.*?)\<', details) #Store details in the array.
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxx/prueba.py", line 54, in <module>
    details=re.sub("\n|\r", "", details) #Separate the details from text
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\re.py", line 192, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

***Thanks for support***

Comment: `TypeError` implies that `details` is getting something like `None`. Try to `print(details)` or better yet, call `type(details)`. That will show you what `details` actually is

Comment: I've alredy done that. And it returned : <class 'requests_html.HTML'>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to know what you are searching for exactly, but you have 2 lines very similar in your code:

```
item_array.append(response.html.search('a-color-price">${}<')[0])
```

and

```
details=(response.html.search('P.when("ReplacementPartsBulletLoader").execute(function(module){ module.initializeDPX(); }){}</ul>;<'[0]))
```

after some messing around, the code and a test page
[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01J6RPGKG/ref=nav_shopall_1_k_ods_tab_sz](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01J6RPGKG)
The first mentioned line of code returns the price,
The second one returns your error - after a closer look, I think that you may have a syntax error in the line:

```
details=(response.html.search('P.when("ReplacementPartsBulletLoader").execute(function(module){ module.initializeDPX(); }){}</ul>;<'[0]))
```

you might want to look at that line - in particularly at the end, I think the bracket is in the wrong place.  the [0])) should be )[0])
That resolves that error and presents a new one ->

```
details=(response.html.search('P.when("ReplacementPartsBulletLoader").execute(function(module){ module.initializeDPX(); }){}</ul>;<')[0])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I think that error occurs for me because the search is returning nothing for me.
For the sake of troubleshooting, if you apply the line you have already say something like this:

change this:

```
details=(response.html.search('P.when("ReplacementPartsBulletLoader").execute(function(module){ module.initializeDPX(); }){}</ul>;<'[0]))
```

to this:

```
details= response.html.search('a-color-price">${}<')[0]
```

The code seems to work fine.

So i'd say your issue first and foremost is syntax and secondly what you might be searching for.

Best of luck with your program and I hope this helps.